# Running another function from an if statement

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following two functions and I'm trying to allow the user to enter a year and then the answer will result in an answer. But, how do I tell the function to recognize a string, and then if the answer is not in MM/DD/YYYY form, to run the function wholePigLatin?Basically, how do I attach the same button to run both functions depending on what the user puts in. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
function isLeaper() {
            var image1 = document.getElementById('yes');
            var image2 = document.getElementById('no');
            var year = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;
            var arr = year.split('/');
            var splitYear = arr[arr.length - 1];
            // 1. If the year is divisible by 4, but not 100.
            if ((parseInt(splitYear) % 4) == 0) {
                if (parseInt(splitYear) % 100 == 0) {
                    if (parseInt(splitYear) % 400 != 0) {
                        $('#myDiv').html(image2).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
                        // alert(year + 'is not a leap year. Sorry!');
                        return "false";
                    }
                    if (parseInt(splitYear) % 400 == 0) {
                        $('#myDiv').html(image1).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);

                        //alert(splitYear + ' is a leap year. Hooray! ');
                        return "true";
                    }
                }
                if (parseInt(splitYear) % 100 != 0) {
                    $('#myDiv').html(image1).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);

                    //alert(splitYear + ' is a leap year. Hooray! ');
                    return "true";
                }
            }
            if ((parseInt(splitYear) % 4) != 0) {
                $('#myDiv').html(image2).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);

                //alert(splitYear + ' is not a leap year. Sorry! ');
                return "false";
            }
        }

        if ((parseInt(year) % 4) != 0) {
            $('#myDiv').html(image2).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
            return "false";
        }
```

My second function is as follows:

```
function wholePigLatin() {
            var thingWeCase = document.getElementById("pigLatin").value;
            thingWeCase = thingWeCase.toLowerCase();
            var newWord = (thingWeCase.charAt(0));

            if (newWord.search(/[aeiou]/) > -1) { 
                alert(thingWeCase + 'way')
            }
            else {
                var newWord2 = thingWeCase.substring(1, thingWeCase.length) + newWord + 'ay';
                alert(newWord2)
            }
        }
```

Here is my button.

```
        <input type="text" id="isLeaper" value="MM/DD/YYYY">
        <input type="button"  value="Is Leap Year?" onclick="isLeaper();">
```

Comment: You know that `"false"==true`?

Comment: @rekire: Actually it's not, but the non-empty string `"false"` is *truthy*

Comment: Could I achieve this by adding a go to in an if statement?

Comment: @Bergi well you are right but `("false"?true:false)===true` strange enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your own functions just as you would call a built-in function (such as parseInt). You just add the line `wholePigLatin();` wherever you want to execute it.

To make a button run one of the two functions: Just introduce a function with an if statement containing your boolean logic and call it at the onClick event:

```
function handleButtonClick() {
    var year = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;

    if( isFormattedAsDate(year) ) {
        isLeaper();
    } else {
        wholePigLatin();    
    }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="isLeaper" value="MM/DD/YYYY">
<input type="button"  value="Is Leap Year?" onclick="handleButtonClick();">
```

You still need to implement the `isFormattedAsDate` function to return true when it is in the correct format, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
function isLeaper() {
    var year = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;
    if ( ! /* year is in DD/MM/YY format */)
        return wholePigLatin();
    // else
    // go on as normal
    // …
}
```

To check for the format, you might want to use regular expressions: `/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(year)`, and also you should return actual boolean values like `true` or `false` from the `isLeaper` function instead of those strings.